# Can this Fritzing diagram be simplified to share a single hole?

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics, fritzing

[image]

I'm playing with my first circuit for my home automation.  I am following this circuit diagram.  It seems to me that I can just combine all 4 legs into the same hole? (the + side of the capacitor, 1 leg of both resistors, the 1 screw terminal)?  I am re-creating this using a perfboard where none of the holes are electrically connected.[image: What I'm using]

Am I wrong in this?  I watched a youtube video on them building this circuit and they indeed did different holes and bridged them together with solder.  Sorry if this is a dumb question, this was a hard one to google.

[image: My attempt]
Row H is the red GPIO36 port of the esp32.
Spot F-10 is +3.3volts
I combined D4 legs all together but didn't have room for the clamp leg too so I bonded it on the other side via C4-D4.
D1 is ground

Comment: You can, the five holes are connected anyway.  You might battle to get a good contact if you put more than one wire in a hole.  You normally do not solder on a breadboard.  Use vero board or similar for soldering.  For expensive chips use sockets when soldering.

Comment: You are quite correct if you use perforated board.

Comment: In general, you should never put more than one component lead or wire into a single hole. This applies to both solderless breadboards as well as PCBs.

Comment: @skvery thanks for the comment.  I think I did it right then.

Comment: Please also post the circuit diagram for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Each column of five holes is one metal strip. You can confirm this with a multimeter or continuity tester.

> It seems to me that I can just combine all 4 legs into the same hole? (the + side of the capacitor, 1 leg of both resistors, the 1 screw terminal)?

Not the same hole; into the same strip. If the strip hasn't enough holes you can jumper out to another strip as is done with the yellow jumper.

> Am I wrong in this? I watched a youtube video on them building this circuit and they indeed did different holes and bridged them together with solder.

You don't use solder on a solderless breadboard. You were looking at a solder perforated board.

---

Now that the question is cleared up ...

[image]

*Figure 1. The "single-wire-per-hole" strategy will make it easier to remove components for circuit modification. The "stuff-them-all-in-one" strategy will make alterations much more difficult but may make tracing easier as it will be obvious what is connected.*

I've only used that type of board a couple of times and found it very difficult to make a good looking job. The standard strip-board or *Veroboard* is much simpler to use and very versatile.

[image]

*Figure 2. Rather neat circuits can be built on Veroboard if the components can be mounted perpendicularly to the direction of the copper tracks. Here there are no flying wires and all cross-connections are done with components or wire links. Image: [Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Streifenrasterleiterplatte_IMGP5364.jpg).*

[image]

*Figure 3. A Vero tool is rotated by hand to remove copper around any hole thereby isolating the strips either side of that hole. This tool doesn't go right through the board as in Figure 1.*

Other options such as solderless breadboard patterned versions exist also.

[image]

*Figure 4. The breadboard-patterned version. Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Pcb33.430-g1.jpg).*

There are many stripboard designers available which allow you to place components, links and break tracks. These can help to generate a plan for a very neat layout.

Comment: I'm re-creating this on a perfboard.  Since I can solder them all together if I wanted won't this work?

Comment: You need to edit your question. It wasn't clear to me. You should also post a photo of the board type you are using. Some have isolated solder pads. Others have lines of connected holes.

Comment: Edited with picture to better explain

Comment: See the update.